# Can you get a medical certificate with degraded vision?

Tags: medical

I am blind in one eye and have a -11.25 prescription in the other, correcting to 20/40. I am afraid to go for a medical and fail, since I was told I couldnt challenge that if I did.

Comment: What country/jurisdiction are you asking about?

Answer (score 3):

No one but your AME is qualified to speak to your specific medical conditions. However, the FAA medical standards [are available online](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/) and you can compare the standards to your vision prescription.

In general it *is* possible to "challenge" a non-issued medical, which is called a "deferral," and receive a special-issuance medical certificate. But this can come at a great cost in terms of both time and money.

The recommendation I have seen is to set up a *consultation*, not a *medical exam*, with an AME. You should be very clear with them that you are **not** trying to have them make a determination on your suitability for a medical certificate, but rather you are requesting an examination to see if they would have any problems issuing a medical certificate if you were to actually apply for one in the future.

---

If you have a valid US driver's license and have never been denied a medical certificate, you can also look into the [Sport Pilot certificate](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/sport_pilot/media/student_pilot%20_guidance.pdf), which has greatly reduced medical hurdles. This certificate affords you very limited flying privileges, but is worth investigating if you are concerned you would not be able to receive a standard medical certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Near as I know, being blind in one eye is not considered a disqualifying medical condition. You can read a list of disqualifying medical conditions [here](https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/medical_certification/faq/response6/).  You can also read about FAA aeromedical dispositions regarding eyes [here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/exam_tech/item31/amd/).

Other than that, per §67.103, §67.203, and §67.303, the only requirements for current myopia is that your vision be correctable to 20/40 or better and near vision correctable to 20/40 or better.

Another excellent resource is the [Aircraft Owners and Pilots Association (AOPA) medical resources site](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/medical-resources/health-conditions).  They had this helpful piece of [information on monocular vision](https://www.aopa.org/go-fly/medical-resources/health-conditions/vision/monocular-vision).